# Unable to understand CocoaPod installation related to tag or version error

Tags: ios, dependencies, cocoapods

I have been stuck with this error for more than 2 days. I am installing pods which have dependencies on some other pods. Now I have changed source of one pod using tag on its repository. And updated the same change throughout other dependency pods. Still it's throwing an error.

[image]

Comment: Please post text as text, not at a picture. Text is so much simpler and easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If you use a self developed pod which is not published on cocoapods cdn, you have to add the pod to your local cocoapods environment and also add the source to your Podfile.
E.g.:

```
add to your podfile (at top level):
source 'https://git.someHostedPodRepository/ios-podspec.git'
```

```
do this in your terminal:
pod repo add ios-podspec https://git.someHostedPodRepository/ios-podspec.git
```

If everything is configured correctly, you also may try

```
pod update --repo-update
```

Comment: I am unable to understand the error itself as to what its trying to say

Comment: Did you try the pod update with "--repo-update"?

The error tells you that the specified version '2.0.1' of UISharedDesign could not be found by cocoapods within your specified sources.
The link where cocoapods searchs for the dependencies is specified with the keyword source in your podfile. Could you provide the podfile? This would make it much easier to understand your config.